# Insert new document to Mongo only if similar one does not exist

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document in a Mongo collection-

```
{
  key1: "someValue",
  key2: "someValue2",
  key3: "someValue3",
  firstSeen: "2021-03-17",
  lastSeen: "2021-03-17",
  timesSeen: 1
}
```

I would like to add this document to Mongo only if a similar document with `key1`, `key2` and `key3` values does not already exist in it.

In case that a similar document does exist, I would like to update the timesSeen (increment by one) and lastSeen (set today's date) values only.

What is the correct and most efficient way to do so? Is there a single command I can use that will be able to do so without searching a relevant document before and inserting a new doc/updating exists one according to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use upsert on update and $and operator to check the key exist and $eq to compare the value

```
db.collection.update({
  $and: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          key1: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          key1: {
            $eq: "someValue"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          key2: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          key2: {
            $eq: "someValue2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          key3: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          key3: {
            $eq: "someValue3"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    
  ]
},
{
  $inc: {
    timesSeen: 1
  },
  $set: {
    key1: "someValue",
    key2: "someValue2",
    key3: "someValue3",
    lastSeen: new Date()
  }
},
{
  upsert: true
})
```

Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kqt3TYCs3Aw

Comment: If this works for you can you accept the answer

Comment: Where does it take the firstSeen from in this example?

Comment: I mean, for the first insertion, where I specify the `firstSeen` value?

Comment: I've added to the second block under `$inc` and `$set` another key `$setOnInsert` with the firstSeen value.